# if I close one of the two forms, both close

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dialog

I have two forms in my application. If I try to close the child form (by clicking on top-right cross), both close.

To show the child form, I'm using `Form.ShowDialog()` after clicking a button. This is the first time it happened and I can't explain this.

```
Private Sub btnShowChildForm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Sysyem.EventArgs) Handles btnShowChildForm_Click

    '...

    Dim formChild As New frmChild
    formChild.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

Comment: Your posted example does not reproduce that problem.

Comment: Create a new project. Copy over the code and try to reproduce the problem with as little code as possible. There's something else going on here that you haven't noticed yet.

Comment: What is the property DialogResult on the `btnShowChildForm`?

Comment: I think you are closing your parent form by 'me.close' in btnShowChildForm_Click..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this from the parent `Form` of `btnShowChildForm`:

```
Me.CancelButton = Me.btnShowChildForm
```

This is how I reproduced a similar behavior:

```
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New()
        Me.testButton = New Button()
        Me.testButton.Text = "CLICK ME"
        Me.testButton.Location = New Point(3, 3)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.testButton)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShowChildForm_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles testButton.Click
        Dim f As New Form2()
        f.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents testButton As Button

End Class

Public Class Form2
    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New()
        Me.btnShowChildForm = New Button()
        Me.btnShowChildForm.Text = "CLICK ME"
        Me.btnShowChildForm.Location = New Point(3, 3)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnShowChildForm)
        Me.CancelButton = Me.btnShowChildForm
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShowChildForm_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowChildForm.Click
        Dim formChild As New Form()
        formChild.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents btnShowChildForm As Button

End Class
```

Comment: How can you possible know he has that code in that event?

Comment: @HanletEscaño "As asked, so answered" But seriously, this is the only why I can reproduce this behavior, given the appended code. If the parent form of the button is shown as a dialog, and that form has the `CancelButton` property set to this button, both forms will close.

Comment: I am not questioning the functionality of your code (I am sure it works) I was just wondering :)

Comment: Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå thanks for your reply, unfortunately my colleague has set incorrectly the property CancelButton

Comment: @MattiaPierdicca Fortunately it's a quick fix:)